# Kafka svc external ip not accessible

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am trying to access kafka svc url externally for that I have exposed the svc url but not able to access the url. when ever I am trying to access the url in any browser, its saying page can't be displayed.

Can you please suggest

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO ! If you want a quick answer, you'll need to share a bit more information. So can you print your configuration and some informations about how you did expose your service, please ?

Comment: does kafka expose any http endpoints ? Share more details like which kafka you installed and how are you exposing the service.